# Unhandled rejection Error: Content-Type header [] is not supported

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, mongoose, mean-stack

I had a elastic query in  my Node.js app as follows. I am using elastic search version 6.2.2. But when I execute the API from postman it shows the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Content-Type header [] is not supported


exports.radix = function (req, res) {
        var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch'),
client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200'
});
client.search({
index: 'xpertradix',
type: 'search',
size: 20,
body: {
  query: {
    match: {
      name: req.param('term')
    }
  }
}
 }).then(function (resp) {
   var data = helper.prepareRadix(resp.hits.hits);
   res.json(data);
});
};
```

I have been struggling for 2 days to fix this. Can someone please help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: On a programming note, if you're using `then`, always remember to add a `.catch` as well, so you can actually debug/inspect your error cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from Elastic search 6 onwards,we must send headers in the query.So I added headers as follows,

```
var client = elasticsearch.Client({
hosts: [{
  host: 'loalhost,
  port: 9200,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}]
```

})

From the following docs,
[Link1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/98)

[LINK2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/host-reference.html)